# better way to handle Connection refused when server is down

Tags: java, sockets

in Java, using Socket to connect into server with the following code will probably generate an error of `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:` when the server is down or not yet started.

```
try {
   Socket clientSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

what is the best way to handle this exception? how do you continue trying to connect until server become available without having this issue?

**UPDATE:**

my method is to use UDP, send message into given port and then wait for a response in a given time, loop until I get a response before starting the socket.

I'm looking for a better approach.

Comment: You could just stick this in a loop couldn't you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415604/java-sockets-best-way-to-retry-upon-connection-refused-exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java sockets: best way to retry upon Connection Refused exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415604/java-sockets-best-way-to-retry-upon-connection-refused-exception)

Comment: same link... yeah, I found it before asking this question, but is it really the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something along these lines:

```
String SERVER_IP = "ip";
int PORT = 0;
int maxTries = 10;
int timeBeforeRetry = 5000; //ms
int count = 0;
Socket clientSocket = null;
while(clientSocket == null && count < maxTries) {
  try {
    clientSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT);
  } catch(IOException e) {
    // Log if you want
    try {
      Thread.sleep(timeBeforeRetry);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) { /* can be ignored or logged I guess */ }
  }
  count++;
}

if(clientSocket == null) {
  // throw some kind of exception
}
```

Comment: Actually I already did this before using UDP to verify the Server. But I guess this the better way, I'm just afraid of something that's why I ask for a better approach. Thank you.